# Choice of Bins in 3D color histogram and HSV color space

Tags: machine-learning, histogram, feature-extraction, hsv, color-space

I am implementing a classifier that is capable of recognizing vehicle color, and I am using the 3D color histograms of the region of interest as a feature vector, computed using openCV's method, `calcHist()`. Specifically, to calculate the histograms, I use `hist = cv.calcHist([hsv_image], [0, 1, 2], None, (8,8,8), [0, 180, 0, 256, 0, 256])`. With these parameters, I got, by doing the `flatten()` of the histogram, a feature vector of 8x8x8 = 512, and with these feature vectors the classifier works pretty well, but I'm looking to further improve the accuracy of my model. So, what I would like to know is if there is any correlation between the number of bins and the range of color channel values, so that I can choose the best number of bins possible.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest if you want to improve accuracy, perhaps try a perceptually accurate colorspace — and HSV isn't one. As color is not "real", and only a perception, it would follow that using a perceptually accurate appearance model is a best practice for your application.

### Perceptual Appearance Models

CIECAM02, CIECAM16, J<sub>z</sub>a<sub>z</sub>b<sub>z</sub> are pretty much state of the art, and there is ZCAM for HDR imagery, and also image appearance models such as iCAM. These might not be available in a library for OpenCV, but most aren't that difficult to implement.

### CIELAB

A simpler model is CIELAB which is part of OpenCV, and is a better choice than HSV or HSL, particularly if you are goal is to judge or select colors in a manner similar to human perception.

L<sup>*</sup>a<sup>*</sup>b<sup>*</sup> breaks the colors down based on human perception and the opponent process of vision. The channels are perceptual lightness, **L<sup>*</sup>** as a value from 0 to 100, and **a<sup>*</sup>** and **b<sup>*</sup>** which encode red/green and blue/yellow respectively, and are each nominally -128 to 127 if using signed 8bit integers.

LAB is a 3D Cartesian space. To determine the color difference, it is simply the euclidian distance between two colors, in other words, the square root of the sum of the squared differences, so:

#### ∆ = ((L<sup>*</sup><sub>1</sub> - L<sup>*</sup><sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (a<sub>1</sub> - a<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (b<sub>1</sub> - b<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> )<sup>0.5</sup>

***Polar Version***
CIELAB is also available with polar coordinates, **LCh**, for Lightness, Chroma, and hue.

*Saturation* is not available with LAB, only Chroma. The other color appearance models I mentioned above do have a saturation correlate, as well as brightness in addition to lightness. (Brightness being a different perception than lightness/darkness).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Hence, can I use this color space to build a flatten 3D histogram to use as feature vector?

Comment: Hi @simone campisi, yes, though I think you might want to use the polar coordinates version (LCh, lightness, chroma, hue)... I answered another question last night and included the code to do so:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69148028/10315269

Comment: But using the polar coordinates I get the coordinate of a single color, right? In my pictures i have the vehicle located in a background,  so there are others colors around the vehicle. So, for this reason I thought that was better to use the distribution of the colors as features vectors.

Comment: @simonecampisi Yes, for LAB the coordinates are L* a* b*, and for LCh the coordinates are L* C* h. An advantage with LCh is the ability to identify a hue "angle" separately from "colorfulness" as defined by C* chroma. With the a* b* cartesian coordinates, the meaning is more abstract.